# Cache with SQL dependency?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, distributed-caching

I know that [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) provides SQL dependency for [Microsoft SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) and [Oracle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database) (10G R4 onwards). I am interested to know what other caching solutions are available, that comes with dependency on Oracle?

Does [Velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_codename_%22Velocity%22), [memcached](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached), etc. support SQL dependency to receive notifications/update the cache automatically, when something changes in the database?

Answer (score 1):

There are some implementations of memcache and NVelocity that support SqlDependency but the ones I know are all paid solutions.
Also you need to keep in mind that generating SqlDependency will fill your database with procedures and tables only used for that purpose....
I'm starting to use http://www.alachisoft.com/ for memory caching. The free version has file dependency and that's really cool!
As for performance, my company build from scratch the implementation that I'm using now.

Hope this help. :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using .NET I would recommend taking a look at the [`System.Web.Caching`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.aspx) namespace, more especifically the class [`CacheDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cachedependency.aspx). I know it has not, at the moment, dependency on Oracle, thou.